# jQuery addClass with function onmouseenter

Tags: jquery

```js
function border() {
  jQuery('.ok').addClass(".f2");
}
```

```css
.ok {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #111;
}

.f2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
  height: 500px !important;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  ;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 4px solid #909090 !important;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ok" onmouseenter="border();">Hello !!!</div>
```

The problem is that it doesn't add the class.

Comment: Classes don't start with `.`, selectors do:  `jQuery('.ok').addClass("f2");`

Comment: I put also with "." and without "." and don´t works

Comment: Your code seems to be running fine when I run your code snippet in this question. The code too, looks fine to me. On mouse enter, I was able to see the class get added and the div got shrunk

Comment: Yes finally the problem it´s with "." yes now works perfect thank´s

Comment: Please don't edit your questions in a way that makes the original problem invisible. Otherwise it's completely useless for future visitors. Also, since this was based on a simple typo, feel free to delete your question.